# How can add value to vb variable in js code?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm try to add a value to my `vb` variable in my `js` code, this is my example

```
<script>
'<%Dim Myvariable As Integer%>' = 201278
</script>
```

but this doesn't work.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how your code works? What sort of event triggers the change in the value? Is there no element (or failing that, a hidden field) that can take the value and have it be extracted later in your VB code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare variable either protected or public:

```
Protected  test As Integer = 201278;
```

And in .aspx file:

```
<script>
    <%=test.toString()%>
</script>
```

edit.

that comment doesn't make any sense @JoséGregorioCalderón the example shows that it IS in script tags. If you mean the file is an external JS file, that is a different problem.

You could solve this in two ways.

1) You serve the JS file as an ASPX file to generate parts of it that are dynamic. you'll need to take care of the headers to serve it is text/javascript

2) You write the variable to your HTML as a data attribute and read it into your JS directly.

i.e.

or...very quick pseudo code.

```
<body id="myBody" data-variable="<%=MyVariable%>">

var bodyElement = document.getElementById('myBody')
alert(bodyElement.dataset.variable);
```